# bochs gives "write to port 0xb004 with len 1 ignored" error

Tags: c, kernel, bochs

I am trying to use ACPI in my kernel development study. When the `port_byte_out(0xB004, 0x0000 | 0x2000)` code is executed, bochs gives 'write to port 0xb004 with len 1 ignored' error. The C function is as follows:

```
void port_byte_out(unsigned short port, unsigned char data) {
    __asm__("out %%al, %%dx" : : "a" (data), "d" (port));
}
```

What does that error means?

Comment: You are passing a 16 bit value to a function expecting a 8 bit value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to be using asm instruction `outb` instead of `out`. `outb` outputs a byte to a port where as `out` writes a 2 byte word.Consider changing the code to:

```
__asm__("outb %%al, %%dx" : : "a" (data), "d" (port));
```

Although you defined the function `void port_byte_out(unsigned short port, unsigned char data)` with a second parameter of `unsigned char data` your example `port_byte_out(0xB004, 0x0000 | 0x2000)` attempted to pass a 2 byte word (short int) as `data`. `port_byte_out` suggests you want that function to output a *byte*. `0x0000 | 0x2000` will get truncated since it is bigger than an `unsigned char`. Most compilers should have thrown a warning about that.

Maybe you meant to have another function:

```
void port_word_out(unsigned short port, unsigned short data) {
    __asm__("out %%ax, %%dx" : : "a" (data), "d" (port));
}
```

Then you could have called it as:

```
port_word_out(0xB004, 0x0000 | 0x2000)
```